# Preserving a jpeg image exif orientation after it's been edited and saved

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As the title says, I need to take an image with exif orientation value of 8 (rotate 270 clockwise), load it into Photoshop, edit it, and save it back to the filesystem with the same exif orientation value of 8.

I know that `Edit > Preferences > File Handling > Ignore Rotation Metadata` will preserve the metadata while I'm editing the image, and `Save As` rather than `Export` will preserve most of the exif in the output. The orientation, however, always saves as `1` (don't rotate).

Is there a setting I'm missing that will preserve the orientation exif as well?

This is a bit of an odd mixture of requirements, so it may help to know why I need to do this.

We're a photography company with a mixture of portrait and landscape images, but our last-stage printing process requires that all images be stored landscape for them to print correctly.

We used to use information stored in a database to display the images in internal and external systems but have recently found that using the exif is more reliable for images which have not been edited.

The last stage of editing a portrait image is always rotating it back to landscape to appease the printer, so we currently end up with an image with the head rotated to the right but exif saying it should be displayed as-is. Saving the original orientation value along with the other metadata seems like the most logical way to overcome this.

Comment: I am surprised your printer cannot auto rotate images for printing. I am not sure about preserving exif orientation, but what about creating an action that rotates when exporting the image?

Comment: We use a program called DP2 to populate layouts that get sent to our print presses. I've never seen anything about it being able to process exif rotation, but even if we could enable it there's millions of photos which may or may not have the correct exif.

I just had a quick look at Actions, but it seems they can only replicate things already available in the interface, so I would still need to work out where exactly I can tell it to preserve the rotation exif metadata

Comment: Is DP2 like a RIP program? Do you have to manually edit each photos exif data? If you do, then I would create an action that rotates the image and does a save-as copy so you still have the original portrait photo, you're not changing the exif data with the action.

Comment: DP2 is a piece of industrial print production software. We don't edit all photos, just a small number for quality control reasons. Having the original copy is of little use to us, since we need the edited version to be printed and displayed on websites / internal tools. Rotating before saving is not an issue for our team, but losing the exif on the edited photo is.